# Missing instructions

Tags: instructions

I have the set 6983 Ice Station Odyssey from when my husband was a kid. Anyone have instructions for it? They seem to have been misplaced. I couldn’t find any online anywhere so I thought I would check here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, LEGO does not offer instructions for this set on their website. Fortunately, there are scanned versions you can find on [letsbuilditagain.com](https://letsbuilditagain.com/instructions/6983/) or [brickinstructions.com](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/6983/Ice_Staton_Odyssey)

Comment: That works! Thank you so much!!